LEGO related software
I just read the tour page and in the section Get answers to practical, detailed questions, it's written Don't ask about ... General support for LEGO related software (i.e. LDraw/LEGO Digital Designer/NXT alternatives). I wonder why and to me, they are about the only thing I might have question, I guess others too. Where should I ask these question ?
This site is in beta, if our questions are considered impractical, it'll close soon.

Possible duplicate of Are questions on 3rd party software on-topic?

The issue is that we are not actually affiliated with LEGO or any of those applications, we're a bunch of enthusiasts, AFOLs, etc. and as such have no greater access to the official support channels than any other customer (it's possible that we have members from the LDraw/Stud.IO, community here, but this isn't their preferred support channel as far as I know).
This is why we rule out "General support" questions - if you've found an issue with those programs you're best off directing your requests at the official channels - for example:

LDraw: https://forums.ldraw.org/ and most likely the "Help" forum.
LEGO Digital Designer: https://www.lego.com/en-us/ldd/support
Mindstorms/NXT/EV3: https://www.lego.com/en-gb/mindstorms/support

However, we are quite good at questions about how to use those programs: Can't get gears to mesh in LDD? We can help. Issues with loops in your EV3 program? We've got you covered.
